# How to Solve this recurrence relation?

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

When I use `RSolve[]`
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
It would show this.
I want to solve it to a[n], the function of n & E
How to do that?

The original recursion relation is
`n a[n] == 2E(n-1)a[n-1] + (1/4)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)a[n-2]`
the result:
`a[0]=1`
`a[1]=a[3]=a[5]=0` ,(a[odd number]=0)
`a[2]=E` constant
`a[4]=3/2E^2+3/8`
`a[6]=5/2E^3+25/8`
.
.
.

```
RSolve[{a[n + 2] == 2 E (2 n - 3) a[n + 1] (1/(2 n - 2)) + a[n] (2 n - 3) (2 n - 4) (2 n - 5) (1/4) (1/(2 n - 2)), a[0] == 1, a[1] == E}, a[n], n]
```

This is my program:
How to edit to get correct results for even terms?

Comment: One question per post please. Please add MA code to Q1.

Comment: First your first question. If you solve it by hand, what do you get for `a[3]`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you tried, not pictures of the code.  A reader trying to help you will wish to copy your code from the question, not type it our by hand..

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: From your original equation you can not get a[0] (because of n*a[n] ). You get a[1] == 0 and all further a[i] are zero.  `origeq = (n a[n] == 
    2 E (n - 1) a[n - 1] + (1/4) (n - 1) (n - 2) (n - 3) a[n - 2]); `  Look at  `(tab = Table[origeq /. n -> i, {i, -2, 6}]) // TableForm `´  `RecurrenceTable[{origeq, a[1] == 0, a[2] == 0}, a, {n, 1, 10}] `  yields `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} `

Comment: The origenial equation is a recurrsion equation. 
`a[0]=1;a[2]=E;a[4]=3/2E^2+3/8; a[1]=a[3]=a[5]=a[odd-number]=0` is initial condition.